# System freezes then reboots but leaves no trace in console, how do I analyze this?

Tags: macos, mac, big-sur

I've been dealing with bewildering system freezes/reboots for months, but they leave no trace in the console at all. I am running macOS Big Sur on a 2019 Mac Pro.

I've done a complete from scratch rebuild twice, and this hasn't changed. Is there some kind of logging setting I'm missing?

Comment: "from scratch rebuild" ...with or without migration/Time Machine restore? Have you run hardware tests?

Comment: What is the output of `pmset -g log | grep -i cause`?

Answer (score 0):

This is really unfortunate situation, my iMac never freezes, very stable OS.
It's hard to debug this problem. Might be software or hardware related, I'll try to give you some of the ideas, hope that helps:

Solving software related issues:

1. Do you run any non-standard (non-sandbox apps/services outside from Apple Store) on your Mac? If yes, try to disable it.
2. Some people reported that Safari causes random freezes on Big Sur. Try changing your browser.
3. Some people reported that Power saving caused issues. Make sure that option "Prevent your Mac from automatically sleeping" in "System Preferences" is on
4. Try updating to MacOSX 12.0 Monterey, maybe Apple patched your problem.

Solving hardware related issues:

1. Run Apple Diagnostics: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731
2. Try to monitor from time to time your temperature sensors using 3rd party software like: https://www.fannywidget.com
   Or monitor manually by running terminal command in Terminal.app every time you start your mac:
   "sudo powermetrics --samplers smc -o /Users/YourUsername/Desktop/temperature.log"